# perl how to use exists to check if hash is in array of hashes

Tags: perl, hash, exists

i have two array of hashes: AH1 and AH2.

```
$AH1 = [  
          {
            'id' => 123,  
            'name' => abc
          },  
          {
            'id' => 456,  
            'name' => def
          },  
          {
            'id' => 789,  
            'name' => ghi
          },  
          {
            'id' => 101112,  
            'name' => jkl
          },  
          {
            'id' => 1389,  
            'name' => mno
          }  
        ];  

$AH2 = [  
          {
            'id' => 123,  
            'name' => abc
          },  
          {
            'id' => 1389,  
            'name' => mno
          },  
          {
            'id' => 779,  
            'name' => ghi
          }  
        ];
```

how can i print hashes of AH1 that are in AH2 using Perl **exists** Function?  or without having to iterate in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exists` locates by index, which are 0,1,2, and not 123,1389,779. `exists` can't help.

Furthermore, you must iterate over both array (one way or another) unless you switch one of the arrays to a hash.

```
$HH2 = {
   123 =>  {
             'id' => 123,  
             'name' => abc
           },  
   1389 => {
            'id' => 1389,  
            'name' => mno
           },  
   779  => {
             'id' => 779,  
             'name' => ghi
           }
};
```

In fact, switching is the easiest way to solve this.

```
my %HH2 = map { $_->{id} => $_ } @$AH2;
for (@$AH1) {
    print "$_->{id} in both\n"
       if $HH2{ $_->{id} };
}
```

It's also quite efficient: You iterate over each array only once.

Comment: the hashes are more complicated and using id only is not enough to verifiy the existance. i have to use 4 keys (headline, started_at, author, name) of the hash.

Comment: If you can't create a key (e.g. `join(':', @{$_}{qw( headline started_at author name )});`), you'll have to use something expensive like `for (@$AH1) { for (@$AH2) { } }`.

Comment: since it is an ARRAY of hash how would you do it with exist?

Comment: Like I showed in the snippet. Just use a more appropriate key than `$_->{id}` (e.g. something like `join(':', @{$_}{qw( headline started_at author name )})`).

Comment: thanks it worked.how would you find the opposite? hashes that are in AH1 but not in AH2?